# What references to "The Man from U.N.C.L.E." are present in Randall Garrett's "Too Many Magicians?"

Tags: the-man-from-uncle, lord-darcy

I was recently rereading *Too Many Magicians* (A Lord D'Arcy novel) by Randall Garrett and the introduction said that there were punnish references to *The Man From U.N.C.L.E.*. Of course the Nero Wolfe references were obvious, but I could not identify the *Man From U.N.C.L.E.* puns. Can someone help with pointing out the references.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just realized the Uncle Nepelear Einzig is also a pun on Uncle Napolean Solo. He is the only relative Lady Tia has left thus another way to show Uncle Napoleon Solo. Also the Man from the Isle Of Man who carries the message is Goodman Colin MacDavid, The (Manx)Man from Uncle. David MacCallum played Ilya Kuryakin the associate (and friend) of Napoleon Solo.

Thanks to @JdeBP who pointed out that Einzig is Solo in German and Tia is Aunt (female Uncle) in Portuguese (or Spanish).

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/einzig#German https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tia#Portuguese https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Neapel#German https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Napoleone#Italian

Comment: Note that this means there's a good chance that Nepelear is Tia's uncle's first name and his last is Einzig, making him Nepelear Einzig, once again Napoleon Solo.

Comment: @MarkOlson Yes I had realized that as well.

Answer (score 14):

It's just one, basically: a subplot of the book involving character's relative who comes from the Isle of Man. So, the Uncle from Man

Comment: OK thanks. I just realized the Uncle Nepelear is also a pun on Uncle Napoleon who is the only relative Lady Tia has left thus Uncle Napoleon Solo. Also the Man from the Isle Of Man is Goodman Colin Mac David. David MacCallum played Ilya Kuryakin the associate of Napolean Solo.

Answer (score 5):

Good answers! Let me toss in a few other easter eggs (besides the Uncle and Nero Wolf references) from the novel:

- The Grand Master of the Guild of Sorcerers is Sir Lyon Gandalphus Grey.  His description is a match for Gandalf, but he is also a deliberate play on L. [Lyon] Sprague de Camp, a major fantasy and SF writer of the time.
- The previous grandmaster of the Guild was Sir Edward Elmer, ThD (Doctor of Thaumaturgy) who invented a jewel which King's Messengers can use to ID themselves -- it glows when the messenger touchers it.  This is, of course, Edward Elmer Smith, PhD who wrote of the Lensmen.

Comment: (And now I'm off to re-read the book!)

Comment: Thanks I have the Lord Darcy book which contains the entire corpus inluding "The Napoli Express" in which the wrong answer is the answer to "The Orient Express" by Agatha Christie

Comment: I see also that Gandolphus (Gandalf) Grey extends that to be the *Grey Magician(